# What are "identities" in itunes connect

Tags: xcode4.5

I tried to upload my app to itunes connect.

I got a message:
`No identities are available for signing`.

I press download identities
`An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded`.

I created a certificate using a private key from my keychain. Is the certificate my identity? Is my private key my identity?

Anyway after that, I tried again.

Same problem.

I can create new certificate in apple developer center. I can create new provisioning profile. I do not see where I can create new "identities". What is that and how to make one?

I created provisioning profile. Still same problem. I think there is something called developer ID. How to create that? I still have the private key. I didn't export developer ID.